# Density of a spherical droplet of water on top of graphene

Tags: molecular-dynamics, gromacs

I produced a spherical droplet of water by having a box of water (sufficient water molecules inside the box to give the right density of water) on top of a 2d sheet-like graphene. The box becomes a spherical droplet under nvt when the graphene is kept in a large box). However, when I calculate the density of water, like along z, I find the density of water low compared to what I started with. Presumably, because the droplet is in a large box now, how can I fix that? or is it what I should expect?[image: Density of water along z-axis] Also, for the perspective, I have attached herewith the image of the set-up as well. [image]

Comment: "The box becomes a spherical droplet under nvt " - can you clarify this bit? Do you mean that you produced the water in a periodic cubic simulation box and then put that configuration in another simulation box (on top of a graphene sheet)?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: "The box becomes a spherical droplet " - then this is something expected. Because previously your water system had no surface due to periodicity, but now you have introduced  free surface to the water system. Now this surface will try to conform to a geometry with the lowest energy i.e. spherical

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't know how can we measure the contact angle of this water droplet with this graphene sheet?

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at these papers - https://doi.org/10.1038/nmat3760, https://doi.org/10.1063/1.5021088. Also, add your MD input file and the configuration files to your post.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot. The MD configuration files are pretty generic. I was able to get a spherical droplet on top of my graphene sheet at NVT. Now, I am struggling to find a correct method to obtain the contact angle. As far as I know with some previous works, I need to measure the time average density distribution of the droplet, and from then on I can measure the contact angle. Is it possible to talk with you through PM?